# Railo stored procedure in cfscript

Tags: railo, cfml

Does Railo have

```
<cfscript>
svc = new storedProc();
</cfscript>
```

It looks like there was some discussion about it in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/Py8R9MtXtSE).

Edit:

I'm trying this:

```
<cfscript>
response = storedproc(procedure="app.GetErrorCodes",result="response",returncode="yes");
</cfscript>
```

And am getting "No matching function [STOREDPROC] found"

Edit 2:

This works:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="app.GetErrorCodes" debug="yes" result="response" returncode="yes" >
</cfstoredproc>
```

Except I don't see a query in the result.

Edit 3:

This works:

```
<cfscript>
storedproc procedure="app.GetErrorCodes" result="response" returncode="yes";
</cfscript>
```

except I don't see a query inside the result.

Oh wait!  I think I found it!
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/railo/UUP0WRuLLX4/zpbKkvekDiAJ

At last!  Whew!  That only took ALL DAY.

Comment: You're better off asking Railo questions on the Railo Google group you linked to before. Their engineers pay attention to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Railo docs](http://railodocs.org/index.cfm/tag/cfstoredproc) site shows this is supported

```
<cfscript>
  storedproc
  [blockfactor="number"]
  [cachedafter="datetime"]
  [cachedwithin="timeSpan"]
  [cachename="string"]
  [datasource="string"]
  [debug="boolean"]
  [password="string"]
  procedure="string"
  [result="string"]
  [returncode="boolean"]
  [timeout="number"]
  [username="string"] {
  }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? I'm not suggesting it doesn't not work (!), but if there's a problem, you should bring it to Railo's attn)